# Flutter app screen navigation using back button on the navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart

If I am controlling the navigation using a switch statement inside of a stateful widget, how would I have the screens go back and forth when the user clicks on the back button on the navigation bar or also by the back gesture which you can do by swiping on the side of the phones.

Here is my current structure -

```
class AuthenticationController extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthenticationController(this.user, this.currentScreen, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  final User user;
  final int currentScreen;
  @override
  State<AuthenticationController> createState() =>
      _AuthenticationControllerState();
}

class _AuthenticationControllerState extends State<AuthenticationController> {
  int currentScreen = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    currentScreen = widget.currentScreen;
  }

  switchScreenFn(int nextScreen) {
    setState(
      () {
        currentScreen = nextScreen;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Center(
          child: Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              //here we want to select what screen to show depending on the current screen;
              switch (currentScreen) {
                case 1:
                  return PhoneNumber(widget.user, switchScreenFn);
                case 2:
                  return OneTimeCode(widget.user, switchScreenFn);
                case 3:
                  return DisplayName(widget.user, switchScreenFn);
                case 4:
                  return ProfilePicture(widget.user, switchScreenFn);
                case 5:
                  return ConversationsController(widget.user, switchScreenFn);
                default:
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text('Authentication!'),
                  );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so easily by wrapping your root widget (Scaffold in your case) with a WillPopScrope widget, it basically intercepts the back action and checks if some certain logic should be done before going back, in your case you have to change the currentScreen variable when the user taps back, and stop the back button handler from popping.

You can read more about it here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html